# Unity C# Calculation not working. Outputs twice in a row with different solutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transition

Code inside a method that gets called in the FixedUpdate()

```
Debug.Log("Tran: " + Mathf.Min(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * (1 / movementSpeedTransitionLength), 1));
Debug.Log("LevelLoad: " + Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
```

After some time the output looks like this:
[Transition gets printed two times while LevelLoad only gets Printed once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUBi0.png)

I cant figure out how the lower value gets calculated. The movementSpeedTransitionLength is equal to 20, so it should need 20 seconds for the code to reach a transition value of 1. The Level Load correctly measures the time until then, also the transition value reaches 1, but only every second time.

Comment: Nothing else is printing “tran”? Is this the only and exact code?

Comment: Yes, I cant remember writing this code twice, also I jumped to the Debug Logs using a double click onto the Console message

Comment: 1. does it do the same in update()? 2. can you try to bot use the second argument? 3. try other debyg.log messages and see if they print twice.